# what is the Difference Between singleton and prototype scopes in Spring 2.5

Tags: spring, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

i read tutorial about spring bean scopes in that they mentioned if bean scope is `prototype` Spring container will create new object every `context.getBean("id")` statement. and if we specify scope is `singleton` it will create only one object even though we write `context.getBean("id")` statement two times or more...
i did small example

```
Demo.java

    public class Demo {
     public static void main(String[] args)
        {

          ApplicationContext con=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spconfig.xml");

          Person p=(Person)con.getBean("person");
          Person q=(Person)con.getBean("person");
          System.out.println(" P hashCode :"+p.hashCode());
          System.out.println(" Q hashCode :"+q.hashCode());
              if (p==q)
              {  
                 System.out.println("Same instance!");
              } 
              else {
              System.out.println("Different instance");  
                   }

        }
}
```

the above program prints

```
 P hashCode :18303751
 Q hashCode :18303751
 Same instance!
```

But in `Person` bean scope i given `scope="prototype"`
why it is printing same Hashcode ????

Explain anyone...

Thanks in Advance...

### spconfig.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"
            "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">

<beans>
    <bean id="person" class="demo.Person" scope="prototype">
       <property name="name" value="Hello World" />
    </bean>  
</beans>
```

### Person.java

```
package demo;

public class Person {
private String name;


public String getName() {
    return name;
}


public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public void printHello() {
    System.out.println("Hello ! " + name);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
 return super.hashCode();

    }


}
```

Comment: There should not be two same objects returned in any way. I just executed your peice of code (Assuming person to be a simple POJO class with an attribute 'name') and I got two different objects !! Have you overridden hashcode() within Person to return something like name.hashCode() ?

Comment: I just tried your newest code and got:  P hashCode :763970039
 Q hashCode :239720060
Different instance

Comment: @ Jintian DENG : Ya problem with Jar files... earlier i placed old jar files later i checked with New jars its working fine....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with Jar file... in earlier i used Spring 2.5 jars it will print same `hashCode`  but later i changed jars, i added Spring 3.0 related jars now i'm getting Correct out put..

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have overridden `hashCode` in your `person` model.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
  return name.hashCode();
```

You execute:

```
Person p=(Person)con.getBean("person");
Person q=(Person)con.getBean("person");
```

twise but for both p and q , `name` property have same value i.e. **"Hello World"**. So it prints same hashCode.

So, without overriding `hashCode`() , output will be different. You will get different hashCode for both p and q.

**EDIT**: Try

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
  return super.hashCode();
```

In your code , and you'll see the difference between singleton and prototype.

Comment: And the [hashcode of String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29) is calculated based on it's characters, not with the default object hashcode, two copies of the same string have equal hashcodes.

Comment: @vertti : yeah exactly . for same string, hashCode would obviously be same. OP should try with super.hashCode() to see actual difference.

Answer (score 0):

As another answer suggested, you have overridden the `hashCode` method, and it is calculated base on the `name` string.

You shouldn't use hash code to verify whether two references are pointing to same object instance.  Compare them directly instead:

```
Person p=(Person)con.getBean("person");
Person q=(Person)con.getBean("person");
if (p==q) {
    System.out.println("Same instance!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Different instance");
}
```

Comment: Yeah i changed the code as you said but it still printing same output.. i edited my code see once...